# fit in vs fit into vs fit in with

Tags: word-meaning, phrasal-verbs, word-difference

I looked up the dictionary but I can't see the differences in the meaning between "fit in" , "fit into" , and "fit in with".

Are there used in different situations?
Do they have different meanings?

Comment: Could you search for and add some examples using each? Then ask about what is not clear to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All three phrases have the meaning of **being** or **becoming a part of**.
However, usage is different.

Things **fit into** *a container* or *something enclosed*

> She tried to **fit into** skinny jeans
>   Having lunch did not **fit into** her schedule.

**Fit in** is used to mean **being a part of a greater whole**.

> The camouflage **fit in** so well, no one saw the soldiers in the forest.
>   They all came from the same hometown, so the all **fit in** together well as a group.

**Fit in with** is an extension of **fit in** possibly naming *something* in particular where the "fit" is.

> His political beliefs didn't **fit in with** the rest of the group.
>   The oasis did not **fit in with** the rest of the desert scenery.

**Fit in** can also be shorthand for **fit in with**

> With his political beliefs, he just didn't **fit in**.
>   *He did't fit with the group*
>
> Looking out over the desert, the oasis didn't **fit in**.

**Fit in** can also be shorthand for **fit into**

> She doesn't **fit in** skinny jeans.
>   She could not **fit in** the meeting.

Comment: I didn't know that an oasis was capable of looking out...